# PF 5.2 Community Edition MeterGaugeChartModel does not seem to work

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

The MeterGaugeChartModel example does not seem to work for me with PF 5.2 Community Edition.  Here is what I am trying:

```
<p:chart type="metergauge" model="#{chartsBean.meterModel1}" style="width:400px;height:250px" />
```

And here is the method in the JSF Bean:

```
public MeterGaugeChartModel getMeterModel1() {
    List<Number> intervals = new ArrayList<Number>(){{
                    add(100);
                    add(100);
                    add(100);
                    add(100);
                    add(100);
                }};
        meterModel1 = new MeterGaugeChartModel(140, intervals);
        meterModel1.setTitle("MeterGauge Chart");
        meterModel1.setGaugeLabel("km/h");
        return meterModel1;
    }
```

And here is the error message that I get in the Javascript Console on Chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

My Bean is defined as such:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ChartsBean implements Serializable {
```

Comment: Hi Balus. Thanks for your answer.  No. I am not including jQuery manually.

Comment: The chart element is inside a form, which is inside a ui:composition element.  The ui:composition element is included in a dialog.  I have 8 other charts inside the same form (line, bar, and pie), and they all display just fine.

Comment: Well, just for grins I took the code from the example and created a test-chart.xhtml page with it, and then created a ChartView bean and that actually works.  So, it must be something related to the <p:chart/> being inside my <ui:composition/> and <p:dialog/> elements or something else like that and Meter charts not liking that.

Comment: Hmmm...changing the code to do this, creates the error again:   List<Number> intervals = new ArrayList<Number>(){{
            add(100);
            add(100);
            add(100);
            add(100);
        }};   It seems that I cannot change the values for the intervals. Why?

Comment: Please create an mcve